# How to set position items to right in FatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to  display items in a FlatList from right to left like this :

[image]

I don't find something like that in the documentation.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `flex-direction: row-reverse`

[image]

This can help you to change items from left to right.

Check this for [further information](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/)

Comment: i try this  : ' <View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}> <FlatList ... /> </View>'. Bt i get the same result

Comment: Update this style inside `Row component`.

Comment: no it doen't work :( . Do you mean  i do like this : rowComponent:'row-reverse' ?

Comment: No. FlatList has Row (i.e icon and label  ). You have to go to Row view container and need to add this style use `flex-direction` properties.

Comment: ah , i understand you  now . But  i fill rows automatically from an array data.